# How to loop a sound without gaps in Android？

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to loop a sound without gaps in android.
I tried to use the code `mediaplayer.setLooping(true)` to loop the sound, but there is always a little pause when the first sound is over and the next sound start.

Comment: I'm new too, but I do have a question. Maybe your sound has gaps in it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the .ogg file format for the sound files in your application. I had this same issue, and after a lot of research , i tried the .ogg format and it loops without any gaps in android.

Info about .ogg format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ogg

You can easily convert your sound file from .mp3 or what have you, to .ogg using the popular open source app [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Comment: Also helped when using `SoundPool`

Comment: Doesn't take effect in my case :/

Comment: Thanks a lot it almost saved my life, I have invested 3 days finding a solution for same.

Comment: you will need to add a new tag (ANDROID_LOOP = true) using some tag editor to that .ogg. And then if you run it via mediaPlayer it may loop without gaps (depends if your sound actually has gaps) NOTE: doing this you may loose control over mediaplayer.setLooping(true). Helpful for ringtone looping using RingtoneManager

Answer (score 7):

this is a bug in the android operating system :(
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18756

Comment: to repeat what others have said, use the OGG format and you're good. I've found that Audacity does a good job of cutting any "blankspace" out of files and saving it to .OGG. Best part is that Audacity is free.

Comment: I tried switching to .OGG, created with Audacity, and did not find it provided gapless playback for my 21 second audio sample.

Comment: You'll have to use Audacity to actually trim the audio file to make it gapless.

Comment: If you mean ensure there is no silence at the start and end of the audio file, yes, I did that.  I also adjusted the waveforms to "zero out" at the start and end of the file.  I can play the sample with Audacity's "Loop Play" (shift-space) command with no audible gap.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Also worth noting is that gapless playback was added with Jelly Bean (API level 16). It allows you to set a secondary mediaplayer that should be used for playing a next audio stream, as long as the primary player hasn't finished playing the current audio yet. This could potentially be used to create a gapless 'loop' too.

[`public void setNextMediaPlayer (MediaPlayer next)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29)

Obviously this won't be of much help for most of the market (currently [< 3% of the devices is running JB](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)), but nevertheless worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

It usually works just fine, unless you have a really slow phone.

I would double check the sound file with an audio editor like Audacity, to verify that it doesn't have any silence at the beginning or end of the file.