# how to play sound looping without gap in android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I want to play a "wav" file of 1 seconds multiple times without gap. All my attemps failed.
My existing code is as follows;

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my5s);
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my5s);
mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
this.mMediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer2);

this.mMediaPlayer.start();
```

I also tried the solutions in the following links;

1. [play .ogg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409657/how-to-loop-a-sound-without-gaps-in-android)
2. [manual looping](http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/03/api-gaps-android-mediaplayer-example.html)

Comment: Did you consider using SoundPool instead, it is well suited for this sort of thing (low latency playback)

Comment: thank you that saved my day. with soundpool I managed to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to program

```
mMediaPlayer.perpare();
```

Comment: This Might Help You

Comment: you might want to explain more your answer? :)

Comment: Hi Hammad Akhtar, are you sure `perpare()` is spelt correctly?